# How can I iterate over a directory and run a script if two files start with the same 8 characters?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I iterate over a directory and pass two file names to another python program or function I have written?

Below is my current script with some output it iterates over a directory and lists the files. I would like to pass two files at a time with the same 8 character prefix to another python program or function I have written which takes the two files as parameters.

What do I need to add to my script to add this functionality?

```
# Process 1. Iterate clean directory
os.chdir('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cleaned_files')
D = {}
fnames = os.listdir(".")
for fname in fnames:
    print(fname)
    date = fname[0:8] # this extracts the first 8 characters, aka: date
    if date not in D:
        D[date] = []
    print D
```

output from above script

```
2012_06_Log.csv
2012_06_Summary.csv
2012_07_Log.csv
2012_07_Summary.csv

{'2012_07_': [], '2012_06_': []}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) will  be helpful here:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for fname in fnames:
    date = fname[0:8] 
    d[date].append(fname)
```

Now iterate over the dictionary values and use [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to get all the pairs related to each key:

```
from itertools import combinations
for f in d.values():
    for f1, f2 in combinations(f, 2):
        #call your function and pass f1, f2
```

---

A simple fix to your code will be:

```
D = {}
fnames = os.listdir(".")
for fname in fnames:
    print(fname)
    date = fname[0:8]
    if date not in D:
        D[date] = []
    D[date].append(fname)
    #or use: `D.setdefault(date, []).append(fname)`
```

And then apply the the `itertools.combinations` part.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution, the use of itertools makes my solution a lot smaller and efficient.